# Как найти все повторяющиеся последовательности из трёх цифр, которые идут друг за другом?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо найти все повторяющиеся последовательности из трёх цифр, которые идут друг за другом.
Пример `696696 878878` Вывести `696696 878878`
Вход `534535345377777753453` Выход `777777`
Мое регулярное выражение

```
import re
s=input()
res = re.findall(r'(?P<test>\d{3})(?P=test)', s)
print(res)
```

При вводе `696696 878878` выводит `['696', '878']`, а надо `696696 878878`
Как исправить?

Comment: А почему 537777775 ->777777, а не 777777777777 ? для каждой семёрки?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FI13xX/1 - тут проверять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> При вводе 696696 878878 выводит ['696', '878'], а надо 696696 878878 Как исправить?

ваша регулярка рабочая, если хотите обязательно использовать именованную группу, то просто возьмите вместо `findall` `finditer`, он возвращает объект `match` у которого много полезных атрибутов и методов:

```
from re import finditer

[m[0] for m in finditer(r'(?P<test>\d{3})(?P=test)', s)]
# ['696696', '878878']
```

либо, как уже было сказано, используйте обычные группы для захвата, а не именованные, но тогда надо джойнить группы

Answer (score 4):

а такой вариант подойдет?

```
(\d{3})\1+
```

`\d{3}` - любые 3 цифры

`(\d{3})` - группа из любых 3 цифр (группа нужна, чтобы потом ее в регулярке использовать)

`\1+` - от одного и больше повторений найденной ранее группы

Comment: Тогда так (\d{3})(\1+)(\D*) , а потом join('', result) иначе не получить 696696 878878

Comment: ну можно же и `' '.join` наверное сделать

Comment: Ok! Можно и так. И через for вывод кортежа списков  тоже еще как вариант:```import re
                                                          s=input()
                                                          res = re.findall(r'(\d{3})(\1+)', s)
                                                          for i in res:
                                                              print(*i,sep="", end=" ")

Comment: будет 696 878, а не 696696 878878

Comment: Проверил в редакторе вывод через for i in res:
    print(*i,sep="", end=" ") все норм: вход 696696 878878 выход 696696 878878

Comment: @ВасилийКалеев  а если во входной строке есть буква или два пробела подряд например?
тогда (\d{3})(\1+)(\D)*

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s=input()
res = re.findall(r'(\d{3})(\1+)', s)
for i in res:
    print(*i,sep="", end=" ")
```

Comment: как на счёт буквы между числами или тире что делать?

Comment: Так что делать?

Comment: @Виктор если у вас возник вопрос, задайте его отдельно, справа сверху кнопка "Задать вопрос".